# Does every sum-of-squares equation have a plane geometric interpretation?

Tags: geometry, elementary-number-theory, euclidean-geometry, diophantine-equations, sums-of-squares

The 2.1.2 sum-of-squares [SOS] equation
$$a^2=b^2+c^2$$
can be thought of in the [regular XY] plane as a right-angled triangle.

> Question: Is there an analogous interpretation for every SOS equation?

For example, does the 2.1.3 SOS equation
$$a^2=b^2+c^2+d^2$$
have an interpretation in plane geometry?

Comment: Just put a few right-angled triangles, the hypotenuse of one being the cathetus of the next.

Comment: "Cathetus" - I've learned something today!

Comment: @user170231 The question asked for *plane* geometry.

Comment: @J.G. My mistake, missed the operative word.

Comment: @totoro: Thanks for “cathetus”! I love learning new words. Now… (1) Can you make your comment an answer, in which you explain exactly how it works (e.g., which of $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ was the original hypotenuse)? (2) In the answer, can you explain how this generalizes to all SOS equations, e.g. $a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2+e^2$? Thanks!

Comment: if we think about the equation to represent a sphere, then limiting it to a plane would be the equivalent of cutting the sphere with the plane, to give circles of variance diameters and centers.

Comment: @KierenMacMillan Every single time that I have to spell that word I have to Google and end up finding the spelling in [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypotenuse).

Comment: Where are the references from? (2.1.2, 2.1.3 etc.)

Comment: @IshanSingh: 2.1.3 refers to the exponent (2) and the number of summands on each side of the equation (1 on the LHS, 3 on the RHS). This is a notational convention going back to at least the 1950s.

Answer (score 11):

$$
a^2=b^2+c^2+d^2
\quad\hbox{and}\quad
p^2+q^2+r^2=s^2+t^2.
$$

[image]

Comment: This is amazing. Thank you!